# Access React context in an API service

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

In my React application I use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to store the user information through the `useContext` hook:

```js
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null!);

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();

    // Implementations of values

    const value = useMemo(() => ({ user, login, logout }), [user]);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

Accessing the auth information works all fine and dandy in the components:

```js
export default function CoolComponent() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  if (auth.user) {
    // Do something
  }
  return <div>Hello {auth.user}</div>;
}
```

The thing is that my jwt-token is stored in the user object and I need it for my API calls in my service, but hooks are not allowed outside functional components. Can I circumvent this in a clever way? Some things that I can think of is to pass the token on every call to the service (not very DRY) or save the token in `localStorage` and then retrieve it from there in the service, but it seems unnecessary to store the same information in two different places?

### Update:

Now with the service code:

```js
const baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

function getToken() {
  // This is what I would like to get some help with
}

const headers = {
  ...(getToken() && { Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}` }),
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

function getAllProjects(): Promise<IProject[]> {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}projects`, {
    headers,
  }).then((response) => response.json());
}

function createProject(project: CreateProjectDTO): Promise<IProject> {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}projects`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(project),
  }).then((response) => response.json());
}

// + many more

export { getAllProjects, createProject };
```

Calling the service in a component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProjects = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const allProjects = await getAllProjects();
      setProjects(allProjects);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  fetchProjects();
}, []);
```

Comment: What do your API calls look like? My initial instinct would be to wrap your API in calls in a re-usable hook that bakes in the token by reading from the context. Then instead of calling the API service directly you call it through a callback return from a re-usable React hook.

Comment: I agree, we need to see the API service code to help make any improvements there.

Comment: I have now updated my answer. I have not much experience in making a custom hook, but I will look into it. The guides on API calls usually have the fetch or at least the URL in the component, but I would prefer to have all API-specific data collected in the service, so I just have to call something like `getAllProjects`. Is either method a better practice?

Comment: How opposed would you be to creating/exposing your API functions in your `AuthContext`? It'd be trivial to create functions there that can directly access the `auth` state and JWT token value.

Comment: @DrewReese Well that is a good suggestion. I will do that.

Comment: Let us know if you hit any snags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) says that you cannot call hooks inside JavaScript functions.

What can you do?

Use custom hooks. rename functions as `useCreateProject` and return your function. Then you will be able to call `useAuth` inside your custom hook:

```
 const useCreateProject =() =>{   
      const {user} = useAuth();
      
      function createProject(project: CreateProjectDTO): Promise<IProject> {
         return fetch(`${baseUrl}projects`, {
         method: "POST",
         headers,
         body: JSON.stringify(project),
        }).then((response) => response.json()); 
      }
 
      return createProject
 }
```

Then call it like this:

```
 const createProject = useCreateProject()
 useEffect(() => {
   const create = async () => {
     setIsLoading(true);
     try {
       await createProject()
     } catch (error) {
       // Handle error
     } finally {
       setIsLoading(false);
     }
   };
   create();
 }, []);
```

But my advice is to store the token on `localStorage` or in cookies. Context data will be lost when user refreshes page. However, if that is not case for you, you can continue using context.